# If a location exist with os.path.isdir by passing a user input variable

Tags: python-2.7, scripting, user-input, os.path

My python code snippet is some what like this

```
CLName = raw_input ("\n\nEnter 7 digits CL number !")

if os.path.isdir("\\\\abc\\\Compiler_Builds\\\something\\\CLName"):                                              
              print  "CL Exists"
```

`\\\\abc\\Compiler_Builds\\something` is a local windows server location. In the above code I want `os.path.dir()` to check if the path `\\\\abc\\\Compiler_Builds\\\something` exists by inserting CLName at end, which will be given by user. I have tried to be as specific as i could. Please let me know if i need to provide more info on this and also please ignore any grammatical or English mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CLName = raw_input ("\n\nEnter 7 digits CL number !")

if os.path.isdir("/abc/Compiler_Builds/something/%s" % CLName):                                              
              print  "CL Exists"
```

You interpolate CLName into the string, as shown.

You don't need to use escaped backslashes, just use forwards slashes.